# How to Move the Nodes Displaying in the Front Page to Another Page? (e.g. domain.com/articles)

Tags: nodes

I've searched almost everywhere and nothing found, so hopefully someone can help me in here!

Okay, I'm using Drupal 7, I installed it and changed the front page to a basic page as I want to have static page displayed rather than list of articles! So this bit is fine and working perfectly, but the problem is how to display a list of my articles on another page, say I'm posting articles regularly and I want to be displayed on the articles section of the website and not on the front page, so how do I do that?

This can be done easily with WordPress 3, but couldn't find a solution for Drupal 7? Anybody have any idea? If you do then please help!

For example http://mydomain.com/articles/ would display a list of my articles, by the way I want each of my articles to be displayed as http://mydomain.com/article/the-article-name

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a view as suggested, but as **'/node'** also contains a list of article teasers as you say, you can create an alias for **'/node'** called **'/articles'** using URL Aliases.

Given that you've changed your front page to a standard page, the default **'/node'** still exists and will receive a teaser from any content that has *'promoted to the front page'* checked under *'publishing options'* when creating a new piece of content.  You can also use the *'sticky at the top of lists option'* if you want an article to remain at the top of your **'/articles'** page.  Example from Drupal6;

[image]

Finally for any new articles you simply assign the URL Alias **/articles/article-name** when creating a new article.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module to create a list of recent articles. In fact views come with a predefined view that emulates the core Drupal frontpage. You just need to enable it and just define another path to use (such as site.com/articles). Here is a good series on learning views http://nodeone.se/blogg/learn-views-screencast-series-summed-up (Not affiliated in any way)